# after Disabled Bitnami banner, Apache not running, Httpd could not be started

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bitnami

I went to restart Apache after disabling the banner with

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --disable_banner 1
```

now Apache won't restart

```
~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
php-fpm already running
apache not running
mysql already running
```

I tried

```
~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
Monitored apache
```

for error log -  cat /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log
you can find it here in this link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f2Xt0bwcMEhKcXkILLMf_kdBl0JoSZUr/view?usp=sharing

for httpd-app.conf file here copy of it in below link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l2zEPzIU0uBHdEyFQEZ22eEPS9fMnBTO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf], [unix.se], or [su].

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

From the log file you shared, I see that Apache fails because there is a mismatch when checking the SSL certificates

```
Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 from /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt and /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key do not match
```

Did you modify them? In case you configured a new SSL certificate, you probably forgot to copy any of the files. If you didn't want to configure a SSL certificate, you can generate new self-signed certificates by running these commands

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key 2048
sudo openssl req -new -key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr
sudo openssl x509 -in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt -req -signkey /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key -days 365
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate

Comment: I installed new SSL certificate now issue solved thank you a lot for you help